# Switching from a motherboard with a Nvidia video card to an Intel based one

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, motherboard, heatsink

I own a Dell Vostro 1710 whose video card is broken (its one of the renowned GeForce 8600M failures).

In an attempt to recondition the laptop, I want to buy the motherboard with the Intel video card for the same laptop. I'll also buy a Dell Vostro heatsink for my laptop model. My question is: is there anything else that I need apart from these two (motherboard and associated heatsink) for the change I want to make? I just want to make sure that I get all the needed information before having a go at it.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing that is broken is the integrated onboard graphics, then I cannot think about anything else that you need to buy, if you are going to reuse all of your other old working components.